# Select only input fields in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a lot of dropdowns, checkboxes and input type text fields in my html code. All of these fields share the same id, which starts with:
`order-billing_address....{field_name}` 
I would like to get only the input type text field ones.

I tried using the `querySelectorAll` method:

```
var billingFields = document.querySelectorAll('*input[id^="order-billing_address"]');
```

but I'm getting a syntax error: `SyntaxError: '*input[id^="order-billing_address"]' is not a valid selector`. How can i make my selector to work ?

Comment: @NickParsons I updated my post to be more clear. they don't have the exact same id, they just start the same

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass the `type`

```js
var billingFields = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="text"][id^="order-billing_address"]');
console.log(billingFields)
```

```html
<input type='checkbox' id='order-billing_address_1'>
<input type='checkbox' id='order-billing_address_2'>
<input type='radio' id='order-billing_address_3'>
<input type='radio' id='order-billing_address_4'>
<input type='text' id='order-billing_address_5'>
<input type='text' id='order-billing_address_6'>
```

Comment: Thnx a lot for the quick answer.  I will accept it in a couple of minutes :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why you have an asterix in your selector. Something like this should work:

```js
var billingFields = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=text][id^="order-billing_address"]');
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the asterisk (`*`) from the beginning & add `[type=text]`:

```
var billingFields = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=text][id^="order-billing_address"]');
```

Comment: Using this, I get all also the checkboxes, as well